# jQuery + CSS | Horizontal Scroll

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to make my div scroll horizontally. My div is 100%, and I want the entire div size (100%) to scroll over to reveal more of the div. Like so:

[image]

I already have buttons that tells JS to scroll +150%, but I doesn't work properly.

Now, heres the situation, my div is 100%, but, within that div, is an image thats 800x500, which I want to vert/hori centre within the 100& div.

So when I press the arrow, I want it to move div1 to div2, and then div2, to div3... ect.

Thanks

[Here is my code](http://jsfiddle.net/oliverj777/xh4xA/)

HTML:

```
<div class= "edge_container" data-stellar-ratio="3">

        <div class = "edge_wrapper">

            <div class="OLLIEJ_Welcome"> <!--id="stage0" data-slide="0">-->
                Hello &amp; Test
            </div>

            <div class="EDGE_idea"> <!--id="stage1" data-slide="1">-->
                IDEAS &amp; CONCEPTS
            </div>

            <div class="OLLIEJ_002"> <!--id="stage2" data-slide="2">-->
                RESEARCH &amp; DEVELOPMENT
            </div>

            <div class="OLLIEJ_003"> <!--id="stage3" data-slide="3">-->
                BUILD &amp; PRODUCTION
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.edge_container{
    position:absolute;
    height: 550px;
    overflow: hidden;   
    width:100%;
    white-space: nowrap;


    display:block;

    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -250px;

    background-color:#00FFFF;
}

.edge_wrapper{
    /*position:absolute;*/
    width: 300%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color:#3366FF;

}

.OLLIEJ_Welcome{
    height: 500px;
    width: 800px;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: normal;
    margin-left: 50%;
    left: -400px;
    padding-left: 2px;

}

.EDGE_idea{
    height: 500px;
    width: 800px;

    display: inline-block;
    white-space: normal;
    margin-left: 50%;
    left: -400px;
    padding-left: 2px;

}


.OLLIEJ_002{
    height: 500px;
    width: 800px;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: normal;
    margin-left: 50%;
    left: -400px;
    padding-left: 2px;
}


.OLLIEJ_003{
    height: 500px;
    width: 800px;

    display: inline-block;
    white-space: normal;
    margin-left: 50%;
    left: -400px;
    padding-left: 2px;

}
```

JS:

```
button_right_0.click(function (e) {
        //dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');

        if(horSlide_0 < 3){
            console.debug("Button Pressed");
            $('.edge_wrapper').animate({marginLeft: '-=100%'},1000, 'easeInOutQuint'); 
            //horSlide_0 ++;
        }
        //hideButtons(dataslide);

    });
```

Comment: Could you please show us the broken code so we can help you fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to have two `div` elements. The first one acts as mask, showing only the content you wish (i.e. each slide). You then have another `div` inside of that which holds all of the elements. Something like this should work for your needs:

```
<div id="slider_mask">
    <div id="slider_content">
        <img src="src/to/img1.jpg" />
        <img src="src/to/img2.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Your CSS should look something like this (you can use jQuery to calculate the overall width of `#slider_content`, based on the `outerWidth()` of its child nodes:

```
#slider_mask {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#slider_content {
    width: 2400px; /* 800 * 3 */
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
    #slider_content img {
        width: 800px;
        height: 500px;
        float: left;
    }
```

Now with your markup, you can handle the `keypress` event via jQuery, to animate `left` property of `#slider_content`:

```
var curr_left = 0,
      content = $('#slider_content');

$(window).keyup(function(e) {
    // Right arrow key:
    if(e.which == 39)
    {
        // Animate to the left if it's not already set:
        if(curr_left <= 0 && curr_left > -1600)
        {
            content.animate({ 'left': (curr_left - 800) }, 'fast', function() { 
                curr_left -= 800 
            });
        }
    }

    // Left arrow key:
    else if(e.which == 37)
    {
        if(curr_left < 0)
        {
            content.animate({ 'left': (curr_left + 800) }, 'fast', function() { 
                curr_left += 800 
            });
        }
    }
});​
```

I have put together a quick jsFiddle to show you a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Y2Ese/

Comment: If you want to replace the `keydown` logic, obviously replace it with your `click()` event for the buttons.

Comment: Getting there, but now my images aren't central (top left), and its not fitting 100%, I can see the next image on the screen (Also, they're not images, they are EDGE builds, but they're still 800x500).

Comment: I've literally copied your example into my site - and it displays two, side by side, half the size.

Comment: Even in your example it doesn't fit 100% ... only 800px, then it shows the next image, which is not what im looking for.

Comment: You need to use JavaScript to get the dimensions, exactly as I indicated in the answer I posted. This isn't a 100% working solution, but it should give you enough basis to edit and get yours working...